# Xcode project build error "No known class method for selector 'labelColor'" for FirebaseUI Pod after pod install

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I just did a pod install and got my Firebase pods updated

[image]

I need the update to use a new feature from Firebase. But I get the following error when I build my project:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    self.textField.textColor = [UIColor labelColor];
    self.label.textColor = [UIColor labelColor];
  }
}

//get the following error: 
No known class method for selector 'labelColor'
```

[image]

another error here:

```
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    attributedLinkText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:privacyPolicyAndTOSString
                                                                attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor labelColor]}];
  }
    //get the following error: 
No known class method for selector 'labelColor'
```

[image]

and the last one here:

```
  if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    if (!self.authUI.interactiveDismissEnabled) {
      self.modalInPresentation = YES;
    }
  }
//get the following error: 
Property 'modalInPresentation' not found on object of type 'FUIAuthPickerViewController *'
```

[image]

if I comment out `//` these errors then the project gets build with no problem.

Here is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'changelater' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks


use_frameworks!

  # Pods for changelater
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Functions'
    pod 'ProgressHUD', '2.51'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '5.7.1'
    pod 'Stripe', '15.0.1'
    pod 'Alamofire', '4.8.2'
  pod 'GooglePlaces', '3.3.0'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '3.3.0'
  pod 'GooglePlacesSearchController', '0.2.1'
#  pod 'GooglePlacePicker', '6.7.0'

end
```

and here is my podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - abseil/algorithm (0.20190808):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/algorithm/container (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (0.20190808)
  - abseil/algorithm/container (0.20190808):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/base (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/base_internal (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/bits (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/config (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/core_headers (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/endian (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/log_severity (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/malloc_internal (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/pretty_function (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/base/atomic_hook (0.20190808)
  - abseil/base/base (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/log_severity
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/base_internal (0.20190808):
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/bits (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/config (0.20190808)
  - abseil/base/core_headers (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (0.20190808)
  - abseil/base/endian (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/log_severity (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/malloc_internal (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait
  - abseil/base/pretty_function (0.20190808)
  - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/throw_delegate (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/memory (0.20190808):
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/memory/memory (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/meta (0.20190808):
    - abseil/meta/type_traits (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/meta/type_traits (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/numeric/int128 (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/strings/internal (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/strings/strings (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/bits
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/internal
  - abseil/time (0.20190808):
    - abseil/time/internal (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/time/time (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/time/internal (0.20190808):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz (0.20190808):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/includes (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (0.20190808)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/includes (0.20190808)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (0.20190808):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
  - abseil/time/time (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/strings
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone
  - abseil/types (0.20190808):
    - abseil/types/any (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/compare (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/span (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types/variant (= 0.20190808)
  - abseil/types/any (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/types/compare (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/optional (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/span (0.20190808):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/variant (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/utility/utility (0.20190808):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - Alamofire (4.8.2)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (= 0.0.3)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.3)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (0.0.3):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.3)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (0.0.3)
  - Firebase/Analytics (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Auth (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 6.5.1)
  - Firebase/Core (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.4.1)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.22.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.6.6)
  - Firebase/Database (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (~> 6.1.4)
  - Firebase/Firestore (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFirestore (~> 1.12.0)
  - Firebase/Functions (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFunctions (~> 2.5.1)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.4.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 1.1)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.4.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - FirebaseAuth (6.5.1):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (1.1.0)
  - FirebaseCore (6.6.6):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.2)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.2.3):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
  - FirebaseDatabase (6.1.4):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
  - FirebaseFirestore (1.12.0):
    - abseil/algorithm (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/base (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/memory (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/meta (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/time (= 0.20190808)
    - abseil/types (= 0.20190808)
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.2)
    - "gRPC-C++ (= 0.0.9)"
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - FirebaseFunctions (2.5.1):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseInstallations (1.1.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.5)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - FirebaseUI/Auth (8.4.2):
    - Firebase/Auth (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.4.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - GoogleDataTransport (5.1.1)
  - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (2.0.2):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 5.1)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - GoogleMaps (3.3.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 3.3.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (3.3.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (3.3.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GooglePlaces (3.3.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base (= 3.3.0)
  - GooglePlacesSearchController (0.2.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.5.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - "gRPC-C++ (0.0.9)":
    - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 0.0.9)"
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 0.0.9)"
  - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (0.0.9)":
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 0.0.9)"
    - gRPC-Core (= 1.21.0)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - "gRPC-C++/Interface (0.0.9)"
  - gRPC-Core (1.21.0):
    - gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.21.0)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.21.0)
  - gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.21.0):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC (= 0.0.3)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.21.0)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - gRPC-Core/Interface (1.21.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.3.1)
  - Kingfisher (5.7.1)
  - leveldb-library (1.22)
  - nanopb (0.3.9011):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.9011)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.9011)
  - ProgressHUD (2.51)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.8)
  - Stripe (15.0.1)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Alamofire (= 4.8.2)
  - Firebase/Analytics
  - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Database
  - Firebase/Firestore
  - Firebase/Functions
  - FirebaseUI/Auth
  - GoogleMaps (= 3.3.0)
  - GooglePlaces (= 3.3.0)
  - GooglePlacesSearchController (= 0.2.1)
  - Kingfisher (= 5.7.1)
  - ProgressHUD (= 2.51)
  - Stripe (= 15.0.1)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git:
    - abseil
    - Alamofire
    - BoringSSL-GRPC
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseAuthInterop
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop
    - FirebaseDatabase
    - FirebaseFirestore
    - FirebaseFunctions
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - FirebaseUI
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
    - GoogleMaps
    - GooglePlaces
    - GooglePlacesSearchController
    - GoogleUtilities
    - "gRPC-C++"
    - gRPC-Core
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - Kingfisher
    - leveldb-library
    - nanopb
    - ProgressHUD
    - PromisesObjC
    - Stripe

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  abseil: 18063d773f5366ff8736a050fe035a28f635fd27
  Alamofire: ae5c501addb7afdbb13687d7f2f722c78734c2d3
  BoringSSL-GRPC: db8764df3204ccea016e1c8dd15d9a9ad63ff318
  Firebase: 32f9520684e87c7af3f0704f7f88042626d6b536
  FirebaseAnalytics: 83f822fd0d33a46f49f89b8c3ab16ab4d89df08a
  FirebaseAuth: a6da11d78dfd956b7f7af3222a0f0b1c93ef8fc9
  FirebaseAuthInterop: a0f37ae05833af156e72028f648d313f7e7592e9
  FirebaseCore: 9aca0f1fffb405176ba15311a5621fcde4106fcf
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 13a6564cd6d5375066bbc8940cc1753af24497f3
  FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop: 296e2c5f5314500a850ad0b83e9e7c10b011a850
  FirebaseDatabase: 0144e0706a4761f1b0e8679572eba8095ddb59be
  FirebaseFirestore: a750487e2019ac35464c78311dcf2fde9d817c52
  FirebaseFunctions: 5af7c35d1c5e41608fecbb667eb6c4e672e318d0
  FirebaseInstallations: acb3216eb9784d3b1d2d2d635ff74fa892cc0c44
  FirebaseUI: e57e9b9c4340631151fbe67a14206d23d0974f37
  GoogleAppMeasurement: e49be3954045b17d046f271b9cc1ec052bad9702
  GoogleDataTransport: 6ffa4dd0b6d547f8d27b91bd92fa9e197a3f5f1f
  GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport: 12f02e5c8f09c055615de90bcd5ba2c375546051
  GoogleMaps: cfee83da305b9aaeccf92c24ac79df11c3003492
  GooglePlaces: 1e2a87bd9efee9623ee65d44ecc35ebfecd7b13c
  GooglePlacesSearchController: e53b61b7497cf40cb18ec296b1d3314c11c0a1c0
  GoogleUtilities: ad0f3b691c67909d03a3327cc205222ab8f42e0e
  "gRPC-C++": 9dfe7b44821e7b3e44aacad2af29d2c21f7cde83
  gRPC-Core: c9aef9a261a1247e881b18059b84d597293c9947
  GTMSessionFetcher: cea130bbfe5a7edc8d06d3f0d17288c32ffe9925
  Kingfisher: 176d377ad339113c99ad4980cbae687f807e20fe
  leveldb-library: 55d93ee664b4007aac644a782d11da33fba316f7
  nanopb: 18003b5e52dab79db540fe93fe9579f399bd1ccd
  ProgressHUD: 54b4c2fa202bf3da7dddc1c698ae4e6376333bd9
  PromisesObjC: c119f3cd559f50b7ae681fa59dc1acd19173b7e6
  Stripe: 2c4d0a88817361a102886315ff452d90f65e898b

PODFILE CHECKSUM: a8be44df63a4bf0f79ac6c00c8c4a6073aa507c5

COCOAPODS: 1.9.1
```

Any idea why I am getting this error on build? and How can I fix it?  I have tried many things such as:

1. command+shift+k
2. pod install --no-repo-update
3. pod update

note: my xcode version is 10.3. It seems like I am getting this error wherever it is about `if (@available(iOS 13.0, *))`. In my podfile I had to force a version on other pods or else it would have caused more error anywhere related to `if (@available(iOS 13.0, *))`

None of these actions working...

Comment: Please post copy/paste versions of the errors and lines that are erroring, not images.

Comment: @pkamb I just edited. Do you know what the problem is here and how I can fix it?

Comment: What’s your Xcode version?

Comment: @jcesarmobile it is 10.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some iOS 13 features are only available if you use Xcode 11 to build and Xcode 10 doesn’t understand them and fail to build.

Comment: Interesting; I just edited my post with a little more explanation about the error and how it happens wherever it relates to`if (@available(iOS 13.0, *))`  what is the solution here then? comment them out? or update the xcode? Tried to update the latest version from App Store but gave me an error that my system doesnt pass the pre requirements.

Comment: this is the error trying to update: Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because macOS version 10.15.2 or later is required.

Comment: You need Xcode 11 to submit new apps, so you should update macOS and Xcode versions

Answer (score 2):

As @jceasarmobile mentioned if your Xcode version is 10, you should update it to the latest one and the build will work smoothly. Otherwise, if you want to stay with your Xcode 10 or Can't upgrade it to 11 or the latest ones, you may want to comment out these parts on the code (all occurrences where the build is failing)

example

```
// if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
//    if (!self.authUI.interactiveDismissEnabled) {
//      self.modalInPresentation = YES;
//    }
//  }
```

This should also help you get away from the build failure.
**Of course, You should follow this only if can't upgrade it to the latest ones.**